# Regex for substring and not substring

Tags: javascript, regex

I need a RegEx pattern in Javascript that will **include** all filenames ending in `.html` and that contain the string `rgo1`.

I also need a RegEx pattern in Javascript that will **exclude** all filenames ending in `.html` and that contain the string `rgo1`.

This is for filename matching in webpack.config, which is why I want the pattern.

Thank you for the "contains" patterns, I found one that works, I will now paste failed attempts at my "does not contain patterns":

```
[^rgo1].*\.html$/gm // nope
(?!^rgo1$).*\.html$ // nope
^((?!rgo1).)*$.*\.html$ // nope
^((?!rgo1).)*.\.html$ //works...paste this in your answer for the win
```

Comment: It's 2 strings, in this case I would essentially be documenting my failed attempts in real time....ok....why not...stand by

Comment: Something like `.*(rgo1).*(.html$)`...

Comment: @DontVoteMeDown, you should escape the period in `.html`: `\.html`. 
 Otherwise, that's the correct pattern for the first question.

Comment: @RickHitchcock nice catch!

Comment: Ok is this question such garbage that I need to remove it here?

Comment: @Likwid_T this is less of a question and more of a request for other people to do your work for you.

Comment: I'm going to https://regex101.com/ to try things out, Am I to assume from the downvotes on this question that I should be copy-pasting every failed attempt in the question?

Comment: @vlaz in your opinion should I delete this question, and not bother StackOverflow with things like this....i.e. Am I abusing the platform with this?

Comment: ^((?!rgo1).)*.\.html$  seems to work so...someone paste this and get the check mark....and I'm sincerely sorry to have bothered you all with this.

Comment: A tool like https://regexper.com/ will help you see what you wrote in a visual way.

Comment: @Likwid_T why use that regex if this simple one works -`/rgo1.*\.html$/` keep it simple, see my answer below

Comment: @RahulDesai I also need the reverse which excludes that substring, which I've included in the question now...

Answer (score 5):

Use the regex: `/rgo1.*\.html$/`

**Regex Explanation:** it will basically match a string containing `rgo1` followed by anything and ending with `.html`.

For the other part of the question just negate the `.test()`

**Demo:**

```js
var filename1 = 'xyzrgo1abc.html';
var filename2 = 'rgo1abc.html';

var regex = new RegExp('rgo1.*\\.html$');

console.log('filename1 test:', regex.test(filename1));
console.log('filename2 test:', regex.test(filename1));
console.log('filename1 negation test:', !regex.test(filename1));
```

Note: For non-regex solution, please see @revo's answer

Answer (score 2):

You don't need Regular Expressions:

```
if ( fileName.includes('rgo1') && fileName.endsWith('.html') ) {
    // Good filename
}
```

If you care about IE:

```js
var fileName = 'rgo1.html';
if ( fileName.indexOf('rgo1') != -1 && fileName.substr(-5) == '.html' ) {
    console.log(true);
}
```

Comment: I would have used this solution [if it had supported IE](https://caniuse.com/#search=includes)

Comment: @RahulDesai then just use `indexOf`. Point still stands - regex is not needed.

Comment: The polyfill for `.endsWith()` is [simple to implement](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/endsWith)

Answer (score 2):

Match any .html containing rgo1

```
\S*rgo1\S*\.html
```

https://regex101.com/r/cW3oFm/1

Comment: Whats with the spaces?

Comment: I'm assuming that file's don't have spaces.

Answer (score 1):

For the not contains regex, try to use:

```
^((?!regol).)*\.((?!html).)*$
```

For the contains regex use @Rahul Desai answer

[Try it Online](https://regexr.com/3p96v)

**Snippet Demo:**

```js
console.log(MatchRegex('index.php'));
console.log(MatchRegex('index.html'));
console.log(MatchRegex('regol.php'));
console.log(MatchRegex('regol.html'));
console.log(MatchRegex('readme.md'));

function MatchRegex(word){
    let regex = new RegExp(/^((?!regol).)*\.((?!html).)*$/);
    return regex.test(word);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Your regex will be `re = /(rgo1)(.html)$/`.

Lets say you have your filenames in `filenamesArray`.

Then you can do:

```
filenamesArray.filter(name => re.test(name))
```

and

```
filenamesArray.filter(name => !re.test(name))
```

to achive what you want.

Comment: `Your regex will be re = /(rgo1)(.html)$/` no, it won't. or it shouldn't because that regex doesn't work.